# C++: object constructor using an array literal directly in the parameter list

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing global constants for my program, and it's important to me that an object's data be as localized and together as possible, so I want to put everything right in the constructor.

The Problem though is that  the constant in this case is an object that takes an array of other objects as an argument.

Things like this work:

```
Constant::Constant(const char * string){...}
const Constant obj("string");
```

but things like this do not:

```
Constant::Constant(const int * array){...}
const Constant obj({1, 2, 3, 4});
```

and things like what I need certainly don't:

```
Constant::Constant(const vec2 * array){...}
const Constant obj({vec3(6, 9), vec3(4, 2)});
```

Am I trying to do this incorrectly, have the wrong constructor parameter types, or are string literals the only array literal that can be placed in the parameter list like this?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you wan to do but it looks like you might want a `std::initializer_list` or `std::array`.

Comment: I think the second call (`..obj({1,2,3,4,};`) results in `std::initializer_list` being used, hence there needs to be a constructor using that. Otherwise a constructor using an STL container may help solve this, since those have constructors taking init lists, in turn.

Comment: @iksemyonov - Looked up `std::initializer_list` and it works exactly as I was hoping, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Besides what has been said in the comment, you may also want to try this (see it live [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ye6mtt6H3qBg2BjC)):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

struct Stru {
  template <std::size_t n>
  explicit Stru(const int (&arr)[n]) {   
    for (int v : arr) {
      std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  Stru obj({1, 2, 3});
}
```